# How to build all combinations of few list or arrays

Tags: c#, list, linq, data-structures

I didnt wrote any code yet as I dunno how to even start it,

I have few lists:

```
List<string> list1 = { A1, B1, C1 }
List<string> list2 = { A2, B2 }
List<string> list3 = { A3, B3, C3 }
```

and I want to build each possible variations by taking one element from each list and build unique list. Looking for way to find all variation.

Let's say we foreach element in list1 we take 1 element from list2 and 1 element from list.

So first variation for list1[0]:

```
A1, A2, A3
A1, A2, B3
A1, A2, C3

A1, B2, A3
A1, B2, B3
A1, B2, C3
```

I want build all variations of strings and save as separated line in list file.
My head cant crawl it how I can code the logic.

Comment: build variations means what? what is the expected output? array? list? how the output will look like?

Comment: *"how I can code the logic"*. You work out the logic first, then you write code to implement it. How would you do it if it was a completely manual process? That's the logic. If you haven't bothered working that out, you shouldn't even be thinking about writing code. Until you've tried something, you haven't encountered an issue to ask about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `SelectMany`of LINQ to get the desired output.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>{ "text1", "text2", "text3" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "text4", "text5", "text6" };
List<string> list3 = new List<string> { "text7", "text8", "text9" };

var allCombinations = list1.SelectMany(x => list2, (x, y) => x + " " + y)
                            .SelectMany(x => list3, (x, z) => x + " " + z)
                            .ToList();
```

my code is based on the data, you provided earlier.

I would suggest you read about [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0)

Comment: thats what Im talking about, thank you, solution works when checked manually, but kinda not understand code :(

Comment: read about SelectMany, I have provided the link in my answer